# Welcome screen like shown in Apollo (iOS reddit client)

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I want to create a welcome screen to show up with every new update with all the new features that are pushed with the new update.

In the Apollo Reddit client on iOS, a beautiful welcome screen shows up with every new update.

I want to know if there is any third party library for this feature or it is created from scratch, Thanks!

[image]

Comment: See Help Center to find out what type of questions are acceptable here.

Comment: you mean the design of the screen and how it looks like a page sheet with a transparent background that shows the home screen ? or do you mean the login for showing this screen whenever there is an update the app should show a screen ?

Comment: I mean the window in the foreground which says 'Happy Halloween!'. It shows up every-time the app gets an update which informs the user with new features.

Answer (score 0):

Some apps show popup like you shared in image when new updateS coming but I dont think they use a library or third party frameworks for it.

They might be - checking app version from database and controlling in `AppDelegate function`. It should be like :

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
     let currentVersion = Bundle.main.buildVersionNumber
     Services.controlAppVersionChanged(currentVersion : currentVersion ,completed : ret in { // a backend service to checking service. Its not real. Just an example.
        if ret == true{
            //CREATE AND SHOW POPUP ON THE TOP OF VİEWCONTROLLER
        }else{
            //DO NOTHİNG
        }
    })

    return true
 }
```

Comment: Wow, this is interesting. This is a great starting point and I'll try it out and post the result here.